# Fully qualified table names with SP_ExecuteSql to access remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server, sp-executesql

Trying to update a table on a linked server (SQL 2000/2005) but my server name will not be known ahead of time. I'm trying this:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParamDef NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @SERVER_NAME VARCHAR(35)

SET @Sql = 'UPDATE
@server_name_param.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeCol=''data'''

SET @ParamDef = N'@server_name_param VARCHAR(35)'

print @Sql

exec sp_executesql @Sql, @ParamDef, @server_name_param=@SERVER_NAME
```

Which returns this:

```
UPDATE
@server_name_param.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable
SET SomeCol='data'
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Any ideas? Is there anyway I view the SQL statement that is being executed after the parameters are bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do this, it can't be parameterised

```
....
SET @Sql = 'UPDATE ' + @server_name_param + '.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable SET SomeCol=''data'''
....
```

Edit: There is another way which I used back in my pure DBA days

```
EXEC sp_setnetname 'AdhocServer', @SERVER_NAME
UPDATE AdhocServer.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable SET SomeCol 'data'
EXEC sp_setnetname 'AdhocServer', 'MeaninglessValue'
```

[`sp_setnetname`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190318.aspx) is there from SQL Server 2000 to 2008

Edit2. [Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191296(SQL.90).aspx):

Try [`EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'login_name'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362(SQL.90).aspx) , where login_name is a superuser

I've not really used this (I use "AS USER" for testing), so not sure of the finer points...

Edit 3: for concurrency, consider using sp_getapplock and a stored procedure, or some other concurrency control mechanism.

Comment: Your eddit actually answers the problem moreso than the question. Doing it this way allows me to execute my query without even using any parameterization or dyanmic sql. Fantastic!

Comment: Oh, but unfortauntely according to msdn this Requires membership in the sysadmin and setupadmin fixed server roles. - roles we don't really want to apply to the application user.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with parameters directly - you would have to use dynamic SQL, or send the server name as a parameter to an SP that does dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @template NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @SERVER_NAME VARCHAR(35) 

SET @template = 'UPDATE {@server_name_param}.dba_sandbox.dbo.SomeTable SET SomeCol=''data''' 
SET @sql = REPLACE(@template, '{@server_name_param}', @SERVER_NAME)

print @Sql 

exec sp_executesql @Sql -- OR EXEC ( @sql )
```

Answer (score 0):

I like gbn's trick.  I didn't know that one and I'm gonna have to research that some more.

Since I didn't know that trick, I've had to use dynamic sql in similar situations in the past (like what Cade posted).   When that happens I would normally query an information schema view to make sure the parameter value is a real database object before building the query.  That way I'm sure it's not an injection attempt.