# Executing multiple dynamic statements together over linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I need to execute three dynamic SQL statements synchronously on a linked server (SQL Server 2005) like this:

```
declare @statement nvarchar(max);

set @statement = 'exec ' + @server_name + '.' + @database_name + '.dbo.Foo;exec ' + @server_name + '.' + @database_name + '.dbo.Bar;exec ' + @server_name + '.' + @database_name + '.dbo.BigTime';

exec sp_executesql @statement;
```

To test this, I have a linked server setup that links to itself.

When executing this local (by removing the `@server_name`), using SQL Profiler I see that it executes just fine as one statement. However, when I execute this via the linked server (using the `@server_name` variable), I see in SQL Profiler that each statement gets executed separately, with `sp_reset_connection` getting executed after each one.

The trace looks something like this:

```
Audit Login ....
exec database.dbo.Foo
exec sp_reset_connection
Audit Logout
Audit Login ....
exec database.dbo.Bar
exec sp_reset_connection
Audit Logout
Audit Login ....
exec database.dbo.BigTime
exec sp_reset_connection
Audit Logout
```

This is causing me problems. Is there any why I can specify to SQL Server to not call `sp_reset_connection` between statements?

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max),
        @exec nvarchar(800) = QUOTENAME(@server_name)
                     + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@databaseName);

SET @sql = N'EXEC dbo.Foo;'
         + N'EXEC dbo.Bar;'
         + N'EXEC dbo.BigTime;';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```

Comment: It's master.sys.sp_executesql, btw. I really liked this idea, but to my astonishment, it's behaving very similar. Using SQL Profiler, I see that it fires the first one, then the second, then fires off sp_executesql with all three as the statement parameter!?!

Comment: ?  This seems to work fine for me:  EXEC master.dbo.sp_executeSQL N'print ''1'';'; ... as for the multiple calls, which server are you running profiler against, the one firing the commands or the one receiving them (@server_name)?

Comment: For testing, I was doing everything locally. I have a linked server that links to itself. I found it really weird that executing sp_executeSQL on the target linked server still resulted in each statement being split up with an sp_resetconnection call.

Comment: @AaronBertrand How about getting output from one of them? I have a piece of dynamic sql that works great for output but I cant seem to get the output now from stringing them together exec? Any thoughts?

Comment: @natur3 can you better define "output"? Do you mean consume a result set, or consume one or more proper output parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You are executing three calls to three linked servers, the result is exactly what you should be expecting (even if the 3 linked servers are not distinct). To achieve what describe, execute the calls as you describe: execute three procedures on one linked server:

```
linkedserver.master.dbo.sp_ExecuteSQL N'
  exec dbname.dbo.Foo; 
  exec dbname.dbo.Bar; 
  exec dbname.dbo.BigTime;';
```

All you have to do is wrap this around in a dynamic built SQL:

```
declare @remoteStatement nvarchar(max), @localStatement nvarchar(max);
set @remoteStatement = N'exec ' + @database_name + N'.dbo.Foo; 
    exec ' + @database_name + N'.dbo.Bar; 
    exec '+ @database_name + N'.dbo.BigTime';
set @localStatement = @server_name + N'.master.dbo.sp_executesql @remoteStatement;';

exec sp_executesql @localStatement, N'@remoteStatement nvarchar(max)', @remoteStatement;
```

Comment: Remus, I posted something quite similar. Your declare line, however, will bomb out.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I fixed it. Serves me right for posting without even doing a syntax check...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not make a single SP on the linked server which calls the other 3 and then just call that one?

Why does the reset connection cause a problem?  Does each SP use some special kind of connection persistent storage like a temp table or something?

Comment: I can't modify anything on the linked server. And yes, resetting the connection is causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
 your stuff here
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

For this you will need distributed transaction coordinator running.

Comment: This didn't work. I get: "The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:3500000006." returned. This was a good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

As per Remus' answer, but avoids some dynamic SQL using `sp_setnetname`. YMMV.

This was asked a day or 2 ago: [Fully qualified table names with SP_ExecuteSql to access remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758686/fully-qualified-table-names-with-spexecutesql-to-access-remote-server/1758716#1758716)

Comment: I didn't know about sp_setnetname actually. Is a neat trick, but can be dangerous in a concurrent environment, multiple callers can change the name on each other and wreak havoc.

Comment: @remus: I used it as a DBA in limited circumstances, to be honest I didn't think it through. I'd use sp_getapplock to control it

Comment: I'm not trying to set the server name as a parameter.

Comment: @Aaron: the same technique applies for dynamic server/database names